# «В районе обеда» – корректен ли оборот?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, разговорная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли в речи использовать оборот «в районе обеда»? Или правильнее сказать «в обеденное время»?

Answer (score 3):

Это сочетание относится к разговорным, в неформальной речи использовать можно. Большой толковый словарь ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD)) фиксирует следующее значение:

> **В районе** *чего,* ***в зн. предлога*** <...> **2.** *Разг.* Приблизительно (о времени). *Встретимся в районе пяти часов.*

[Предложения со словосочетанием «в районе обеда»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B2+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0) используются в современной литературе, например:

*Первый клиент появился **в районе обеда,** он поздоровался со мной за руку...* (Дарья Донцова, 2009)
*Она выехала из дому **в районе обеда,** и поначалу всё шло хорошо*
(Мария Семёнова, 1999).
*Также он добавил, что мы с ним поднимались в гостиницу вместе **в районе обеда*** (Лера Волкова, 2021).